# why "==" operator does not work

Tags: java, list, arraylist, double

the targetPixValList is a list contains Double objects and it contains also similar values in successive position in the list, and when i tried to compare two Double values using Code_1, the cnt returns zero.
and when i used code_2, the cnt returns value.

and the type of the list is

why "==" operator does not work with Double?

Code_1:

```
int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cs.targetPixValList.size()-1; i++) {
        if (cs.targetPixValList.get(i) == cs.targetPixValList.get(i+1))
            ++cnt;
    }
```

Code_2:

```
 int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cs.targetPixValList.size()-1; i++) {
        if (cs.targetPixValList.get(i).equals(cs.targetPixValList.get(i+1)))
            ++cnt;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare objects, use `.equals(Object)` instead.

Comment: what is the type of `targetPixValList` ?

Comment: @erencan `Double` - it's stated in the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `.equals(otherObject)` when comparing objects. You're comparing `Double` which is an object. If you were using `double` instead, a primitive, you could use == to compare values.

Alternatively, get the `double` value from `Double` object:

```
if (yourDoubleObject.doubleValue() == otherDoubleObject.doubleValue()) {
  // Do some things
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`Double` is a class wrapper for primitive `double`. When comparing instances of `Double` (or object references) use `equals` method rather than `==`.

Also, for your case, the comparison of `Double` by using `equals` could also give wrong results due to float point comparison (done behind the scenes). If you're working with sensitive floating points values, I recommend using `BigDecimal` instead of `Double` and use `BigDecimal#compareTo` rather than `equals` because `BigDecimal#equals` does not take into account the scale, while `BigDecimal#compareTo` does.

Comment: I think if we are doing just "comparision", then the `equals` method of Double should be sufficient.

But yes, if arithmatic operations such Add, divide, etc. are being performed, then we would need to: 1. Convert Double to Big Decimal, and  2. Specify the "Rounding" mechanism to be used to handle overflow scenarios if any.

Comment: @Mecon when using `BigDecimal`, it's better to use `BigDecimal#compareTo(anotherBigDecimal) == 0` rather than using `BigDecimal#equals` because `equals` does not take into account the scale, while `compare` does. This is one of those odd cases in the JDK where the `equals` and `compare` methods are not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

`==` operator gives correct results in primitive types like `int`, `long`, `double`. If you use the operator with objects it will compare the references by default.

Using `equals` method may give the correct result dependingof the object. You should override `equals` method to receive logically check if the objects are equals.

For `Double` object, ,it also checks the referance equivalence of the objects. You should use `Double#doubleValue` method to check value equivalence.

Here is the code;

```
 for (int i = 0; i < cs.targetPixValList.size()-1; i++) {
        if (cs.targetPixValList.get(i).doubleValue() == cs.targetPixValList.get(i+1).doubleValue())
            ++cnt;
    }
```

**See also :**

[How to override equals and hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/892994)